# Signed measure: descending sequence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(X, A)$. Why does not follow that for every descending sequence $(A_j), A_j \in A, A_{j+1} \subset A_j$, that

$\mu ( \cap A_j) = $ lim $\mu(A_j)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Lebesgue measure $\mu$ on the real line $[n,\infty)$ decreases to the empty set but $\mu ([n,\infty))=\infty$ for all $n$ so $\mu ([n,\infty))$ does not tend to $\mu (\emptyset)$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! 
Other assumption: Let $(\mu_n)$ be a sequence of measures on $(X, A)$. Let's assume that for all $C \in A$ there exists the limit $\mu(C) = lim \mu_n (C) \in [0, \infty]$. Why does not follow that $\mu$ is a measure on $(X, A)$?